# Sales confirmation emails not sent after SUPEE 10266

Tags: email, magento, magento-1.9

I'm on a CE 1.9.3.1, already patched with previous patches available. It has a custom theme, based on rwd theme.

As I install SUPEE 10266, the sales confirmation emails are not sent anymore. All the emails don't seem to be affected by this issue, as the registration confirmation is sent to a new customer who registers through "create a new account" or during checkout process.

Answer (score 0):

... Just a Noob error!

As I'm trying to install SUPEE 10266 in a test environment, I just had forgotten to set up cron jobs correctly in it!